# How to inherit class variable type from constructor?

Tags: typescript

I am writing a validator class, something like

```
class Validator {
  private path: string;
  private data: unknown;

  constructor(path: string, data: string) {
    this.data = data;
    this.path = path;

  }

  public isString() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Right now my data is of type `unknown`, but I'd like type to be inherited from constructor i.e.

```
const validator = new Validator("HomePage", 123); // data in class should be inherited as number
```

with functions I usually did something like

```
function<T>(path: string, data: T) {  }
```

But I am unable to figure out how to do it with classes. In particular inheriting from constructor

Comment: [Do you mean something like this?](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBqYgJYBMwBcD2AnAPAFQD5oBvAKGmgActEA3dAUyvQAsAuaCNGgOwHMA3OSo16aJqjRgOeIcOAYeXLAFdgmLAApKrDssT8ANNEnToeAJQlhFNC0QQAdKegBeE+jBCKt+0512bsx2chQAvqTClCoARkjA0A4AytwGfJpWxNAA9ABU0I6F0LnZ0BERpDwMAO5wCCjo2Dj6-ASaAEQBLO3G7QBmGBjtFkJVtfBIktgdXT3Q7TFgWMNyoJAwKbx8Ew0a0AwAHuI8yDA7U7gtfERZFWPQm2nnjVqdrHMLYABeK6RAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really similar as with functions:

```
class Validator<T> {
  constructor(private path: string, private data: T) {

  }
}

const validator = new Validator<string>('', '');
```

Also that's not called inheritance, it's just a generic parameter.

You also shouldn't have `private path string`, constructor parameters already do that for you.

Comment: Just to add to this - the generic value `<string>` can be omitted and TS will still try to guess it. For example `new Validator("", "hello")` will automatically infer `T` to be `string`. Passing an explicit generic argument is still fine but might not be needed in some cases, If you want something like `new Validator<"hello" | "world">("", "hello")` then you do need to be explicit, however.